# Angular2 Query Parameters Undefined

Tags: angular

My site is a hierarchy of components that look like this.

- App
- ... Header
- ....... SearchBar
- ... Content
- ....... PageSearchResults
- ....... Page2
- ....... Page3
- ... Footer

App manages the router outlet and changes the content based on the URL. I search for "lord" using an input text field in the SearchBar component and navigates to the following URL:

```
http://localhost:4200/search/lord
```

It loads up the PageSearchResults in the content area as expected and I can read from the query parameter with the following code:

```js
var query = "";
this.route.params.forEach(params => {
  query = params['query'];
});
```

Works like a charm. Now I want for the text input field in the SearchBar component to show the same value as the query parameter. If I copy-paste the above code into the SearchBar component, it no longer works. It will say that params['query'] is undefined. If I put my SearchBar component into the PageSearchResult component instead of the App component, it will work just fine.

Is there some sort of black voodoo about who can read the query parameters in the URL?

Comment: As always, use a shared service. Read the param from the search controller, pass it to a shared service. Emit the new param from that shared service. In the search bar, subscribe to the observable in the shared service, and update the param value of the component.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Isn't controllers part of the AngularJS and not Angular2? Also, I would still like to know the logic behind the URL and why only certain components are able to read from the query parameters.

Comment: Yes, but it's a terminology issue. Replace controller by component in my previous comment. The params are read from a service named ActivatedRoute, which is related to the current route being activated. Your search bar componentis not linked to any route.

Comment: My SearchBar Component is listening for changes to the URL and using the ActivatedRoute passed to the constructor. Surely it must be possible to read parameters from the query even if the component wasn't being routed to, but still a living component?

Comment: I doubt it. The doc says: "Contains the information about a route associated with a component loaded in an outlet." The search bar component doesn't qualify.